# dpkg-deb error -- enlightment problem

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, enlightenment

I tried to install enlightenment by the ppa, but I got the following error:

```
Unpacking libefl (1.19.1-0zesty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl_1.19.1-0zesty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/evas/utils/evas_image_loader.ps', which is also in package libevas-loaders:amd64 1.8.1-2build3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl_1.19.1-0zesty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know, how to remove *enlightenment* and now Unity gives me some errors.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl_1.20.7-0bionic0_amd64.deb
```